# Raster map not found error with r.fill.dir

Tags: qgis, gdal, grass-gis, dem, depression-filling

I am new the GIS world and I am having trouble with generating depressionless DEM from lidar elevation data. I am using GRASS 7.6.1 and QGIS 3.4.12.

I have used r.fill.dir successfully on a different section of the same master DEM. I have set the region to the extent of my raster layer, and filled any no data values in the raster.

I keep receiving the same error.

I am not a coding inclined person but and as such I simply utilize the GRASS modules in the processing toolbox. I have attached the logs from a succesful trial and an unsuccessful one, and tried to highlight the lines where it seems to fail.

```
Algorithm 'r.fill.dir' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-f' : False, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'areas' : 'C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/6c3c806ba2c242a3a555b50dd5cca5b2/areas.tif', 'direction' : 'C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/0afcdb6221b849c39f8da418494d91ee/direction.tif', 'format' : 0, 'input' : 'D:/SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019/Work Areas/Cow Creek/CCDEMBB1.tif', 'output' : 'C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/617dc6b370974cde803a21bc73905166/output.tif' }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=17 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
r.external input="D:\SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019\Work Areas\Cow Creek\CCDEMBB1.tif" band=1 output="rast_5dcc2cf1ac3aa9" --overwrite -o
g.region n=4766286.0 s=4755640.0 e=408782.0 w=396516.0 res=2.0
r.fill.dir input=rast_5dcc2cf1ac3aa9 format="grass" output=output199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191 direction=direction199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191 areas=areas199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191 --overwrite
g.region raster=output199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191
r.out.gdal -t -m input="output199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\617dc6b370974cde803a21bc73905166\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=direction199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191
r.out.gdal -t -m input="direction199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\0afcdb6221b849c39f8da418494d91ee\direction.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=areas199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191
r.out.gdal -t -m input="areas199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\6c3c806ba2c242a3a555b50dd5cca5b2\areas.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Executing <C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=17 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>r.external input="D:\SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019\Work Areas\Cow Creek\CCDEMBB1.tif" band=1 output="rast_5dcc2cf1ac3aa9" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Reading band 1 of 1...
**Link to raster map <rast_5dcc2cf1ac3aa9> created.
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>g.region n=4766286.0 s=4755640.0 e=408782.0 w=396516.0 res=2.0
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>r.fill.dir input=rast_5dcc2cf1ac3aa9 format="grass" output=output199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191 direction=direction199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191 areas=areas199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191 --overwrite
Reading input elevation raster map...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100**
Filling sinks...
Determining flow directions for ambiguous cases...
Found 661352 unresolved areas
Repeat to get the final directions...
Found 72525 unresolved areas
Writing output raster maps...
0..6..12..18..24..30..36..42..48..54..60..66..72..78..84..90..96..100
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>g.region raster=output199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>r.out.gdal -t -m input="output199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\617dc6b370974cde803a21bc73905166\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Float64>
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal complete. File <C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\617dc6b370974cde803a21bc73905166\output.tif> created.
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>g.region raster=direction199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>r.out.gdal -t -m input="direction199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\0afcdb6221b849c39f8da418494d91ee\direction.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <UInt16>
Input raster map contains cells with NULL-value (no-data). The value 65535 will be used to represent no-data values in the input map. You can specify a nodata value with the nodata option.
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal complete. File <C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\0afcdb6221b849c39f8da418494d91ee\direction.tif> created.
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>g.region raster=areas199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>r.out.gdal -t -m input="areas199213c24f724609afb80f3b1e954191" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\6c3c806ba2c242a3a555b50dd5cca5b2\areas.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Int32>
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
WARNING: Too many values, color table cut to 65535 entries
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal complete. File <C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\6c3c806ba2c242a3a555b50dd5cca5b2\areas.tif> created.
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 2086.59 seconds
Results:
{'areas': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/6c3c806ba2c242a3a555b50dd5cca5b2/areas.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'direction': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/0afcdb6221b849c39f8da418494d91ee/direction.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/617dc6b370974cde803a21bc73905166/output.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'r.fill.dir' finished
```

Unsuccessful:

```
Algorithm 'r.fill.dir' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-f' : False, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'areas' : 'C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/17da3a80cf764139affb6eb52099574d/areas.tif', 'direction' : 'C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/5cb4e6374cf24988b80455b9cbc30f40/direction.tif', 'format' : 0, 'input' : 'D:/SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019/Work Areas/TalfourdCreek/TalfDEMBBs.tif', 'output' : 'C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/cac8da580cf6474f9f78c08af2bbefdc/output.tif' }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=17 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
r.external input="D:\SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019\Work Areas\TalfourdCreek\TalfDEMBBs.tif" band=1 output="rast_5dcc1a4f1a18d8" --overwrite -o
g.region n=4754490.776602141 s=4730612.776602141 e=393451.2349311542 w=377611.2349311542 res=2.0
r.fill.dir input=rast_5dcc1a4f1a18d8 format="grass" output=output6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8 direction=direction6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8 areas=areas6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8 --overwrite
g.region raster=output6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8
r.out.gdal -t -m input="output6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\cac8da580cf6474f9f78c08af2bbefdc\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=direction6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8
r.out.gdal -t -m input="direction6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\5cb4e6374cf24988b80455b9cbc30f40\direction.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=areas6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8
r.out.gdal -t -m input="areas6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\17da3a80cf764139affb6eb52099574d\areas.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Executing <C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=17 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>r.external input="D:\SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019\Work Areas\TalfourdCreek\TalfDEMBBs.tif" band=1 output="rast_5dcc1a4f1a18d8" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Reading band 1 of 1...
**Link to raster map <rast_5dcc1a4f1a18d8> created.
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>g.region n=4754490.776602141 s=4730612.776602141 e=393451.2349311542 w=377611.2349311542 res=2.0
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>r.fill.dir input=rast_5dcc1a4f1a18d8 format="grass" output=output6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8 direction=direction6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8 areas=areas6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8 --overwrite
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>g.region raster=output6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8
ERROR: Raster map <output6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8> not found**
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>r.out.gdal -t -m input="output6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\cac8da580cf6474f9f78c08af2bbefdc\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR: Raster map or group <output6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8> not found
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>g.region raster=direction6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8
ERROR: Raster map <direction6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8> not found
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>r.out.gdal -t -m input="direction6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\5cb4e6374cf24988b80455b9cbc30f40\direction.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR: Raster map or group <direction6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8> not found
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>g.region raster=areas6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8
ERROR: Raster map <areas6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8> not found
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>r.out.gdal -t -m input="areas6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8" output="C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\17da3a80cf764139affb6eb52099574d\areas.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR: Raster map or group <areas6fdb2f1f5b434fb2953958ff9c6f1aa8> not found
C:\Users\bpmri\OneDrive\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\bpmri\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Press any key to continue . . .
Execution completed in 959.19 seconds
Results:
{'areas': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/17da3a80cf764139affb6eb52099574d/areas.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'direction': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/5cb4e6374cf24988b80455b9cbc30f40/direction.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/cac8da580cf6474f9f78c08af2bbefdc/output.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/17da3a80cf764139affb6eb52099574d/areas.tif</li><li>C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/5cb4e6374cf24988b80455b9cbc30f40/direction.tif</li><li>C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_29a9cb17175945dda3faf7adbf6f5d5f/cac8da580cf6474f9f78c08af2bbefdc/output.tif</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

EDITED to add gdalinfo for .tif files

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Raster information' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : 'D:/SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019/Work Areas/Cow Creek/CCDEMBB1.tif', 'MIN_MAX' : False, 'NOGCP' : False, 'NO_METADATA' : False, 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_32d0288029af4e0dabf88d4b38dd0968/c7b59db90d6b4ed38043f5a5796db924/OUTPUT.html', 'STATS' : True }

GDAL command:
gdalinfo -stats "D:/SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019/Work Areas/Cow Creek/CCDEMBB1.tif"
GDAL command output:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF

Files: D:/SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019/Work Areas/Cow Creek/CCDEMBB1.tif

Size is 6133, 5323

Coordinate System is:

PROJCS["NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 17N",

GEOGCS["NAD83(CSRS)",

DATUM["NAD83_Canadian_Spatial_Reference_System",

SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],

TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

AUTHORITY["EPSG","6140"]],

PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],

UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],

AUTHORITY["EPSG","4617"]],

PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],

PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],

PARAMETER["central_meridian",-81],

PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],

PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],

PARAMETER["false_northing",0],

UNIT["metre",1,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],

AXIS["Easting",EAST],

AXIS["Northing",NORTH],

AUTHORITY["EPSG","2958"]]

Origin = (396516.000000000000000,4766286.000000000000000)

Pixel Size = (2.000000000000000,-2.000000000000000)

Metadata:

AREA_OR_POINT=Area

Image Structure Metadata:

INTERLEAVE=BAND

Corner Coordinates:

Upper Left ( 396516.000, 4766286.000) ( 82d16'13.71"W, 43d 2'31.98"N)

Lower Left ( 396516.000, 4755640.000) ( 82d16' 6.61"W, 42d56'46.94"N)

Upper Right ( 408782.000, 4766286.000) ( 82d 7'11.69"W, 43d 2'37.64"N)

Lower Right ( 408782.000, 4755640.000) ( 82d 7' 5.43"W, 42d56'52.58"N)

Center ( 402649.000, 4760963.000) ( 82d11'39.36"W, 42d59'42.37"N)

Band 1 Block=6133x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray

Minimum=0.000, Maximum=221.770, Mean=189.377, StdDev=38.980

NoData Value=1.79769313486231571e+308

Metadata:

STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=221.77000427246

STATISTICS_MEAN=189.37711132672

STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0

STATISTICS_STDDEV=38.980257093889

STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100

Execution completed in 2.17 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_32d0288029af4e0dabf88d4b38dd0968/c7b59db90d6b4ed38043f5a5796db924/OUTPUT.html'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Raster information' finished
HTML output has been generated by this algorithm.
Open the results dialog to check it.
```

and

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Raster information' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : 'D:/SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019/Work Areas/TalfourdCreek/TalfDEMBBs.tif', 'MIN_MAX' : False, 'NOGCP' : False, 'NO_METADATA' : False, 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_32d0288029af4e0dabf88d4b38dd0968/7c9a24ba8dbd4433b5a798aa107068ed/OUTPUT.html', 'STATS' : True }

GDAL command:
gdalinfo -stats "D:/SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019/Work Areas/TalfourdCreek/TalfDEMBBs.tif"
GDAL command output:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF

Files: D:/SCRCA Floodplain Mapping 2019/Work Areas/TalfourdCreek/TalfDEMBBs.tif

Size is 7920, 11939

Coordinate System is:

PROJCS["NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 17N",

GEOGCS["NAD83(CSRS)",

DATUM["NAD83_Canadian_Spatial_Reference_System",

SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],

TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

AUTHORITY["EPSG","6140"]],

PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],

UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],

AUTHORITY["EPSG","4617"]],

PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],

PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],

PARAMETER["central_meridian",-81],

PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],

PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],

PARAMETER["false_northing",0],

UNIT["metre",1,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],

AXIS["Easting",EAST],

AXIS["Northing",NORTH],

AUTHORITY["EPSG","2958"]]

Origin = (377611.234931154176593,4754490.776602140627801)

Pixel Size = (2.000000000000000,-2.000000000000000)

Metadata:

AREA_OR_POINT=Area

Image Structure Metadata:

INTERLEAVE=BAND

Corner Coordinates:

Upper Left ( 377611.235, 4754490.777) ( 82d29'59.69"W, 42d55'59.61"N)

Lower Left ( 377611.235, 4730612.777) ( 82d29'41.01"W, 42d43' 5.76"N)

Upper Right ( 393451.235, 4754490.777) ( 82d18'21.03"W, 42d56' 8.17"N)

Lower Right ( 393451.235, 4730612.777) ( 82d18' 4.76"W, 42d43'14.26"N)

Center ( 385531.235, 4742551.777) ( 82d24' 1.61"W, 42d49'37.10"N)

Band 1 Block=7920x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray

Minimum=0.000, Maximum=214.225, Mean=163.673, StdDev=64.573

NoData Value=1.79769313486231571e+308

Metadata:

STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=214.22512817383

STATISTICS_MEAN=163.67271123317

STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0

STATISTICS_STDDEV=64.573337177383

STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100

Execution completed in 5.74 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/bpmri/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_32d0288029af4e0dabf88d4b38dd0968/7c9a24ba8dbd4433b5a798aa107068ed/OUTPUT.html'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Raster information' finished
HTML output has been generated by this algorithm.
Open the results dialog to check it.
```

Comment: `r.fill.dir` is not `Reading input elevation raster map...` as in the successful instance. From there all fails. The first raster is named `...BB1.tif` but the second is `...BBs.tif`. Both files have the same type of data in band 1?

Comment: Correct, both have the same data and were cropped from the same master DEM.

Comment: Could you include in the question the `gdalinfo` output for both files?

Comment: Thank you. Could you tick on the *Read and display image statistics (force computation if neccesary)* option in the *Raster information* algorithm GUI?

Comment: Image statistics included